# How can I give users access to thier data without requiring any authentication?

Tags: authentication, sensitive-data-exposure, web-authentication

The premise of this question boils down to frictionless access to data. I have User A whose records I have kept on a database.

I want to send them a link to their records such that they can access their records without having to sign into any kind of portal or Auth system.

This is my current approach:

```
Endpoint --> https://companyname.com/<Cipher-text>
```

where cipher-text is unique to each user. The decrypted Cipher-text will be used to lookup user records in the database.

The issue is anyone who happens to get the endpoint URL might end up the records.

I know I can periodically regenerate the Cipher for more security but assuming that there are bad actors and User A does not wish to engage with the system beyond seeing their records, What could a solution be?

Is there a more efficient and secure way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately the question is missing a usable threat analysis. One the one hand you just assume for no explained reason that an attacker might get access to the secret URL. On the other hand you don't want the user to use secrets not available to the attacker (i.e. proper authentication). This does not match. Usability and security requirements usually conflict with each other. To find the right balance for a specific use case one has to analyze the threats in more detail to find out which risks are acceptable in favor of better usability. Such analysis is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you think will be acceptable for the users. If you want to avoid usernames and passwords, so that they won't have to remember anything more to be able to access your system, then you might consider implementing some kind of email-based authentication.

You could make that a one-time link, sent via email to the user. The first time the user visits that link, a cookie is stored in their browser. After that, that link becomes invalid and visiting it will have no effect at all. The cookie might expire at the end of the session, or be persistent, depending on your needs. When the user drops or invalidates the cookie (by closing their browser, or deleting the cache, or clicking on a logout button, etc.), or when your server decides to invalidate the cookie (after a fixed time, etc.)., the user will then have to request another one-time link, which will be sent to their email address.

That way, user authentication will be based on either of these factors:

- **Access to the user's email account.** This is something only the user is supposed to be able to do. Most websites with single-factor authentication actually rely on the security of the user's email account.
- **Access to the user's cookies**, which basically means access to the user's browser or machine. This is usually an acceptable way to authenticate, unless you need to protect the users in situations where they might share their machines with others. Depending on your needs, you will have to decide whether you want to make cookies expire after a long time, or at the end of the session, or after a fixed short time even before the session is over.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a reversible cipher text here. It's a fairly common design to do `https://companyname.com/<128-bit guid>` and clicking that link gives access to the document without needing login. As long as the GUID is fully random, then nobody's going to be able to guess it. You can see this in action in Google Drive when you create a Share Link to a document.